# Assignment to non-const reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 Update 3 compiles this with no error and no warning. Yet I was under the impression that temporaries could only be bound to const references. Is this non-conformant or am I misunderstanding something?

```cpp
struct Foo {};
Foo Func6() { return Foo(); }

TEST(Arguments, NonConstReference)
{
   Foo& bob = Func6();
}
```

EDIT

The question linked by marcinj is the same issue, although that question is not specifically about VS2015 and was not located when I typed this one up.

I had tested using /W4 to see if I got a warning and didn't see one, but testing it again I find that now I do. When opening the project properties to adjust a setting VS2015 has a habit of showing the properties dialog set for a different build configuration than the currently selected one, a most unhelpful behaviour that has caught me out many times, (and will I'm sure continue to do so).

As is mentioned in that other question using Disable Language Extensions (/Za) makes this an error, but is unfortunately not a usable solution as Microsoft's own platform headers won't then compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MSVC compiler has a non-standard extension, enabled by default, which allows temporaries to bind to non-`const` references. To disable this, use the [command-line option `/Za`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) or the corresponding Project Property.

Comment: Never understood the use of this.

Comment: @GillBates even more useless when you have rvalue refs!

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Of course, this extension predates rvalue references by at least one decade, so I don't think that's fair comparison.

Comment: @Angew although this is the VS2015 compiler we are talking about here, so MS has had plenty of opportunity to fix it.

Comment: Marking this as the answer although it's worth noting that using /Za will cause MS own platform headers to fail to compile, so that's rarely a useful workaround.

Comment: In VS2017 there is `/permissive-` to disable permissive mode.

Comment: @Neutrino How would you fix this without breaking **tons** of legacy code?

Comment: @Angew Easily. MS should fix their platform headers to not rely on this feature, then the compiler extension that enables this behaviour should be added to a separate 'legacy mode' option that is _not_ on by default.